# Slowly increase jButton size

Tags: java, interface, jbutton

Hi I was trying to make a dock-like effect on an interface for a project in school. I just need a couple of buttons to be bigger when I hover over them, this I've managed to achieve. The problem is it happens immediately whereas I would like it to be a slow transition between the original size and the new one. This is what I've tried to do:

```
public void biggerButton(JButton boton) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = 0;
            while ( i < 10) {
                boton.setSize(i + boton.getWidth(), i + boton.getHeight());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    };
    runnable.run();
}
```

The code runs when the mouse enters the button placed on a container. If someone could give me a hand I would very much appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Try redrawing the window and use the thread safe methods of swing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: So, basically, what you want to do is ***animation*** (of UI components' size). In that case, your current approach of increasing the size directly in pixels based on loops, ***is wrong***; because different users' systems will run at different speeds, making the animation inconsistent; and because there are situations where the animation needs to be interrupted or even reversed mid-way through, like, in your case, if the user moves the mouse out of the button before the "grow" animation ends. ***The right way to do animations is with a*** `Delta-Time` (#GoogleIt), as used in game-development.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to do. I could do it in the end by using a couple of libraries and animations

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum you need to put the code that affects Swing components on the event dispatch thread:

```
while (i < 10)
    {
    final int adjustment = i;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
            {
            @Override
            public void run()
                {
                boton.setSize(adjustment + boton.getWidth(), adjustment + boton.getHeight());
                }
            });
    }
```

If you are using Java 8, lambdas make this code much nicer:

```
while (i < 10)
    {
    final int adjustment = i;
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () ->
            { boton.setSize(adjustment + boton.getWidth(), adjustment + boton.getHeight()); }
    }
```

Swing, like all GUI toolkits I have worked with, is not thread-safe and so changes may only be made on the event thread.

Note, too, that you are only increasing it by 1 pixel for each step for a total of 10 pixels. That might not be very noticeable.

Comment: Thank you for the help I did the adjustments you mentioned to my code and it's much nicer. But what I really wanted is to add a delay between each time the button increases in size like add 1 pixel of width wait 5 milliseconds so as to give some aesthetic. Actually what I want to do is a dock like this [link](http://www.yoannkubera.net/realisations/librairies-java/)